# Having a variable reference an object in VBA

Tags: vba, variables, object, reference

I'm writing some VBA code to dynamically position some elements on a form. What I would like to do is create a two dimensional array of references to 11 rows of label and text box objects, then step through the array and position each "row" differently based on the properties of the above rows.

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find a way to store the references! The following code 
produces the error: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

```
Dim fields(10,10) 
fields(0,0) = txtFirstName
```

If I assign an object to a single variable like so

```
Dim field 
field = txtFirstName
MsgBox field.Top
```

Then I get no error message from the assignment, but the reference to field.Top gives me the error "Object Required".

Please, what am I doing wrong here. I'm new to stack overflow and VBA coding so forgive me if this is an easy fix, but I've leveraged my google-fu and I'm just not finding a solution. Many thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: You should declare your variables with specific type, e.g., `Dim field As Object`, and then per @Tom Cannaert's response, use the `Set` keyword when assigning an object variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the Set keyword, since you are dealing with object references.

```
Set fields(0,0) = txtFirstName
```

The reason you get the error, is because VBA will default to the text property of the textbox, giving you a string instead of the textbox object.